# Calling method from a different class and keeping it non-static

Tags: java, methods, static

I am building a blackjack simulator to further my java skills and am having a problem getting the classes to communicate with each other when it comes to hitting.

I am creating a Human class that will contain the methods common to the players and dealers, hit being one of them.  I have a class Deck, which creates the deck of cards and this class has a method, getCard.  In Human, I want the hit method to call getCard from the Deck class.

I do not want to make getCard static, since this method needs to remove a card from the deck which is an instance variable of the Deck class.  I also don't want to create a new instance of deck inside the Human class, since I only want one deck per game, not one deck per human.

How can this be done properly?  Right now, the IDE (Netbeans) says "cannot find symbol, Method Deck() on this line in the hit method in Human,

```
hand.add(Deck().getCard());
```

Here is the getCard method from the Deck class:

```
//Removes a random card from the deck and deletes it from the deck.
//It removes one card per call to the function.
    public Card getCard(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());

        Card toDeal = new Card (deck.get(index).getName(), 
                                deck.get(index).getSuit(), 
                                deck.get(index).getValue());

        deck.remove(index);

        return toDeal;
    }
```

And here is the hit method from the Human class

```
public void hit(){
    hand.add(Deck().getCard());
}
```

In case I didn't include something, I am including both classes:

```
package blackjack;

import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

    private static int numSuits = 4;
    private static int numRanks = 13;
    private static int numCards = numSuits * numRanks;

    private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public Deck() {

        String suit = null;
        String name = null;        
        int value = 0;
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for (int i=1; i<=numSuits; i++){
            for (int j=1; j <= numRanks; j++){
                switch (i){
                    case 1: suit = "Clubs"; break;
                    case 2: suit = "Diamonds"; break;
                    case 3: suit = "Hearts";  break;
                    case 4: suit = "Spades"; break;
                }

                switch (j){
                    case 1: name = "Ace"; value = 0; break;
                    case 2: name = "Two"; value = 2; break;
                    case 3: name = "Three"; value = 3; break;
                    case 4: name = "Four"; value =4; break;
                    case 5: name = "Five"; value = 5; break;                             
                    case 6: name = "Six"; value = 6; break;
                    case 7: name = "Seven"; value = 7; break;
                    case 8: name = "Eight"; value = 8; break;
                    case 9: name = "Nine"; value = 9; break;
                    case 10: name = "Ten"; value = 10; break;                           
                    case 11: name = "Jack"; value = 10; break;
                    case 12: name = "Queen"; value = 10; break;
                    case 13: name = "King"; value = 10; break;                           
                }

                Card card = new Card (name, suit, value);  
                deck.add(card); 
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return deck.size();
    }

    public void printDeck(){

        for (Card card : deck){
            System.out.println(card);
        }
    }

//Removes a random card from the deck and deletes it from the deck.
//It removes one card per call to the function.
    public Card getCard(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());

        Card toDeal = new Card (deck.get(index).getName(), 
                                deck.get(index).getSuit(), 
                                deck.get(index).getValue());

        deck.remove(index);

        return toDeal;
    }
}
```

And the human class (which is incomplete):

```
public class Human {
    private int handValue;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;

    public Human(String name){
        this.handValue = 0;
        this.name = name;
        this.hand = null;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getHandValue(ArrayList<Card> hand){

        for (Card card: hand){
            handValue += card.getValue();
        }

        return handValue;
    }

    public void hit(){
        hand.add(Deck().getCard());
    }


}
```

And lastly, the constructor from the card class:

```
public Card(String name, String suit, int value){
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: try `hand.add((new Deck()).getCard());` - make an anon instance of `Deck` and call its `getCard()` method.  Or, you could modify the method `hit()` to `public void hit(Deck deck){
    hand.add(deck.getCard());
}`

Comment: can you not just pass a reference to Deck to your Human objects?

Comment: It would involve significant reworking but Having the Deck object track what player has which cards (and having players keep a list that has their cards as well for ease but this doesn't need to be a bunch of references back to the Deck) might be easier in the long run?

Comment: @clearlyspam23, that is ultimately the solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @ThatDaveGuy, I think I would rather pass the deck around and have each person keep track of their own hand like in real life. We'll see what happens as the program grows.

Comment: I see the appeal of that and would probably start with that approach were I you. Having just one thing keep track of who has what cards might be simpler in the long run though. Fewer comparisons. Isn't the deck going to have to keep track of which cards have been dealt out anyway? Adding information about who they were dealt to should be pretty quick

Comment: @ThatDaveGuy.  Right now, the deck is an ArrayList, it has no memory of which cards were dealt as they are simply deleted from the ArrayList.

Comment: @user2926358 sorry for being lazy and not looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not yet creating *any* instance of a Deck.

Create an instance of Deck somewhere with `new Deck()`.

You could then share references to this one Deck via:

- Create a class `Game`, and in it create one `Deck` and pass a reference to it to the `Human` instances.
- Make `Deck` a singleton class. [Note: Singletons are frequently frowned upon - what if you later want to manipulate multiple decks in the same application?]

For example, here's how you could pass a `Deck` reference to a `Human`:

```
    class Human {
          ...
          private Deck deck;

          public Human( String name, Deck deck ) {
              ...
              this.deck = deck;
          }
```

And then here's how you would implement `hit()`:

```
          public void hit(){
              hand.add( deck.getCard());
          }
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.  This seems to make the most sense. When looking at your code, it seems like every Human will have its own deck, but so long as it is passed in rather than newly created with each call to Human, it doesn't matter.  What is a little hard to wrap my head around, is that every Human will have it's own copy of deck, but when playing blackjack in real life, that is not the case.  I suppose one alternative is to pass the deck only when the hit method is called as suggested by @blurfus above.

Comment: @user2926358 - With the code above, every Human does *not* have its own copy of the deck. Instead, every Human has a *reference* to a Deck instance. You can give all the Humans references to the same, single, shared Deck instance. All the object variables in Java are references, not the objects themselves.

Comment: In which case it perfectly resembles real life.  There is one deck sitting on a table that everybody draws from.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is one of **references**, in that you must make sure that Human has a Deck field that refers to the actual Deck in use, and then have the `hit()` method call the Deck instance's `getCard()` method. You can pass the valid reference to the actual Deck in Human's constructor or in a `setDeck(Deck deck)` setter method.

---

As an aside, note that playing cards are often used as a classic use case for using enums. For instance:

```
enum Rank {
   ACE("Ace", 1, 11), TWO("Two", 2, 2), THREE("Three", 3, 3), 
   FOUR("Four", 4, 4), FIVE("Five", 5, 5), SIX("Six", 6, 6), 
   SEVEN("Seven", 7, 7), EIGHT("Eight", 8, 8), NINE("Nine", 9, 9), 
   TEN("Ten", 10, 10), JACK("Jack", 10, 10), QUEEN("Queen", 10, 10), 
   KING("King", 10, 10);

   private int value1;
   private int value2;
   private String name;

   private Rank(String name, int value1, int value2) {
      this.value1 = value1;
      this.value2 = value2;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getValue1() {
      return value1;
   }

   public int getValue2() {
      return value2;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}

enum Suit {
   CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
}

class Card {
   private Rank rank;
   private Suit suit;

   public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
      this.rank = rank;
      this.suit = suit;
   }

   public Rank getRank() {
      return rank;
   }

   public Suit getSuit() {
      return suit;
   }

}

class Deck {
   List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

   public Deck() {
      for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
         for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
            cards.add(new Card(rank, suit));
         }
      }
      Collections.shuffle(cards); // shuffle them
   }

   // other methods including deal here
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen that about cards.  I have no experience with enums but planned on doing that after I got the game working.  However, looking at how much shorter the code is, it is quite tempting to do now.